# Speed difference between two MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

## Scenario:

Assume you have two tables: Table A and Table B. Table A contains 100 million rows, Table B can contain some if not all of the rows in Table A.

```
# Table A
,----,-------,------,---------,-------,---------,
| id | email | name | surname | score | updated |
'----'-------'------'---------'-------'---------'
# INDEXES
PRIMARY email
INDEX   date_open
INDEX   date_click
INDEX   date_send
INDEX   score

# Table B
,-------,-------,---------,
| email | score | updated |
'-------'-------'---------'
# INDEXES
PRIMARY email
INDEX   score
```

## Question:

Assume that you need to choose between one of the two queries, which one would you choose?

```
REPLACE INTO `Table_B` (`email`,  `score`, `updated`) SELECT `email`, `score`, `updated` FROM `Table_A`;
REPLACE INTO `Table_B` (`email`,  `score`, `updated`) SELECT `email`, `score`, `updated` FROM `Table_A` WHERE `updated` = 'yes';
```

Which query will be faster? Would adding an index to `updated` in Table A speed up the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *not* do the millions of rows in a single query.  Something would go wrong -- some timeout, some buffer limit, something.  Then it would fail -- for MyISAM the task would be partially done, with no way to know where it left off.  For InnoDB, it would spend a lot of time rolling back what it had partially done.

I am dubious about the Question...  Which is it...

1. Copy just the `scores` from the wide, tall, table `A` to the narrower, shorter `B`?  That's multi-table `UPDATE`.  Or maybe just recreate `B` as a `SELECT .. FROM A`.
2. `B` contains the 'new' scores and they need to be copied into `A`?  That's also a multi-table `UPDATE`.
3. There might be new rows in the 'source' table.  That needs IODKU.  But what about the other columns?
4. A massive copy like this is sometimes indicative of the 'wrong' schema design.  That is, if your data flow does this periodically, then simply keep the scores in a separate table, and `JOIN` as needed.  Do *not* go through the task of updating the table, when a separate table with just scores is sufficient.  But... Maybe this won't work because "not all" the scores come in??

Back to my point about "too big to do in a single pass".  Your `PRIMARY KEY(email)` makes it easy to walk through one table and do the `UPDATE` or `IODKU` with the other table in steps of, say, 1000 `emails`.  Here is a discussion about how to such chunking:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks
Note the `SELECT email FROM tbl WHERE email > $left_off ORDER BY email LIMIT 1000,1` as the technique to find the end of the next chunk.